# Angle between two lines

Tags: c#, math

I need to find angle between two line in my c# program. Can someone help me to calculate the points if only start end poinst given.

[image] 
for line L1 starting point(X1,Y1) and End point (X2,Y2) Given same as for L2 also

Comment: Look up "dot product".  You can easily calculate the cosine of the angle knowing a minimum about vectors.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to get the two vectors `v1` and `v2` the two lines and normalize them to the length of `1`. Then,

```
angle = acos(v1•v2)
```

where: • = 'dot' product and `acos` = inverse of cosine.

But be aware, there are always two possible results: `a1` and `a2` where `a1+a2 = 180°`